# SQL "With As" Alternative Way

Tags: sql, temporary

In a previous question, you guys helped me grab data from a different row. The statement I am using works perfectly on the MS SQL Server Managment Studio. I can run the statement without any errors and I return the data I need. However, I need to run this data on our frontend program. When I try to run my statement on this program, it just hangs. I have a feeling that the "With As" part of this statement is causing problems. Is there anyway to rewrite this statement by putting this temporary table in a subquery?

```
WITH Temp1 AS (SELECT
SkillTargetID = Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID,
LogoutDateTime = Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime,
LogonDate = DateAdd(s,-1 * Agent_Logout.LoginDuration,Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID ORDER BY Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime ASC) RowVersion,
LoginDuration = Agent_Logout.LoginDuration
FROM Agent_Logout)

SELECT
AgentID = Base.SkillTargetID,
LogonDate = Base.LogonDate,
BaseLogout = Base.LogoutDateTime,
BaseDuration = Base.LoginDuration,
NextLogon = Temp1.LogonDate,
LogoutDuration = DateDiff(s,Base.LogoutDateTime,Temp1.LogonDate)
FROM Temp1 Base
LEFT JOIN Temp1 ON Base.SkillTargetID = Temp1.SkillTargetID
AND Base.RowVersion = Temp1.RowVersion-1
```

Comment: How do you execute the sql in you program?

Comment: I copy and paste the exact same code from what executes correctly in MS SQL Studio 2005 into our Cisco front end program. I get an error code of Invalid query. Error near the keyword WHERE. This is odd since I don't have a WHERE clause in the statement.

I have tried adding a blank and a valid where clause into the statement but this just causes the program to hang. No error code is given.

Comment: This sounds like possibly some problem with your front end program modifying things? What if you chuck all of the query into a view then try selecting from that in your front end program?

Comment: No go on that. I have no write access to any part of the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I ended up with. This works with the Cisco front-end program we use.

```
DECLARE @dtStartDateTime DATETIME, @dtEndDateTime DATETIME, @agentid VARCHAR
SET @dtStartDateTime = :start_date SET @dtEndDateTime = :end_date
SELECT
    FullName = Temp1.FullName,
    AgentID = Temp1.SkillTargetID,
    LogonDate = Temp1.LogonDate,
    LogoutDate = Temp1.LogoutDateTime,
    LoginDuration = Temp1.LoginDuration,
    RowVersion# = Temp1.RowVersion,
    AgentID2 = Temp2.SkillTargetID,
    LogonDate2 = Temp2.LogonDate,
    LogoutDate2 = Temp2.LogoutDateTime,
    RowVersion#2 = Temp2.RowVersion,
    LogoutDuration = DateDiff(s,Temp1.LogoutDateTime,Temp2.LogonDate)

FROM

(SELECT
    FullName = Person.LastName + ', ' + Person.FirstName,
    SkillTargetID = Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID,
    LogoutDateTime = Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime,
    LogonDate = DateAdd(s,-1 * Agent_Logout.LoginDuration,Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID ORDER BY Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime ASC) as RowVersion,
    LoginDuration = Agent_Logout.LoginDuration
    FROM Agent_Logout, Agent, Person
    WHERE Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID = Agent.SkillTargetID and Agent.PersonID = Person.PersonID
) Temp1,

(SELECT
    SkillTargetID = Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID,
    LogoutDateTime = Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime,
    LogonDate = DateAdd(s,-1 * Agent_Logout.LoginDuration,Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID ORDER BY Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime ASC) as RowVersion
    FROM Agent_Logout
    WHERE Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID = Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID
) Temp2

WHERE Temp1.SkillTargetID = Temp2.SkillTargetID and Temp1.RowVersion = (Temp2.RowVersion - 1) AND
(Temp1.LogonDate >= :start_date 
And Temp1.LogonDate <= :end_date) AND
Temp1.SkillTargetID IN (:agentid)
ORDER BY Temp1.SkillTargetID, Temp1.RowVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to materialise it you can do

```
;WITH Temp1 AS (
SELECT
SkillTargetID = Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID,
LogoutDateTime = Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime,
LogonDate = DateAdd(s,-1 * Agent_Logout.LoginDuration,Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Agent_Logout.SkillTargetID ORDER BY Agent_Logout.LogoutDateTime ASC) RowVersion,
LoginDuration = Agent_Logout.LoginDuration
FROM Agent_Logout)

SELECT * INTO #Temp1 FROM Temp1


SELECT
AgentID = Base.SkillTargetID,
LogonDate = Base.LogonDate,
BaseLogout = Base.LogoutDateTime,
BaseDuration = Base.LoginDuration,
NextLogon = #Temp1.LogonDate,
LogoutDuration = DateDiff(s,Base.LogoutDateTime,#Temp1.LogonDate)
FROM #Temp1 Base
LEFT JOIN #Temp1 ON Base.SkillTargetID = #Temp1.SkillTargetID
AND Base.RowVersion = #Temp1.RowVersion-1
```

It don't really understand what you mean by hanging when running on your frontend program though. Are you using the query exactly as written or are you parameterising it in some way?

Are you running it against the same data both times?

Comment: I am running this query against the same DB in both cases. The front end program is a Cisco program. Would using your way eventually fill the server with all of these temp tables or are erased after use?

Comment: @Gilbert - No temp tables are automatically dropped by the server when the connection ends. You might be better dropping explicitly actually but in any event after your clarification I doubt this change to using a temp table will make any difference.

Comment: I still get an error code of Invalid query. Error near the keyword WHERE.

Comment: @Gilbert - Yep. Sounds like your front end app must be doing something weird. I would suggest using Profiler to see the statements sent but I presume you won't have permissions to do that.